# My App crashes when iCloud status changes

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6, icloud

I know there is a similar question but the OP seems to think his problem was only on the simulator and so not such an issue...  But I think mine is in both.

I was having a problem adapting an app for iCloud storage (when trying to observe for `NSUbiquityIdentityDidChangeNotification`).  I could not see what the problem was with my code and so...

...after hours of banging my head against a wall I have set up a **new** project in Xcode (v6.1 6A1046a) to try and narrow it down.  It seems it must be a very basic problem indeed...

The **only** things I have done in this new projects are:

1. Enable iCloud capabilities for 'Key-value storage' and for 'iCloud
   Documents'(using the default container) - no error messages, appears to be set up fine.
2. Add a label and a button to the provided view controller in IB.
3. Add an IBOutlet for both and hook up an IBAction to change the label text when pressed.

For clarity, the **only** code I added to an empty 'Single View Application' template  is:

```
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.label.text = "You pressed the button"
}
```

So if I run the project from Xcode in the simulator or on the device, or if I run the project directly on the device, it launches fine and the button works properly - as you would expect...

**The problem is:**

If I am running on the device from Xcode & I go to the Settings->iCloud->iCloud Drive on the device and toggle the switch for my app (from/to either state) the app crashes.  I'm getting no feedback except this:

[image]

If I am running the app directly on the device and try and toggle iCloud Drive setting, when I go back into the app it appears to restart (the view is being reset, along with the label.text - neither of which happen if I just visit settings without touching the switch).

It also has the habit of freezing my device completely, which is mildly irritating.

I'm new to iCloud development so I guess I may be missing something really basic...

As I say it's an empty project with only a couple of lines of additional code so it's probably not something I HAVE done.  Which limits it to something I HAVEN'T done. I am trying to follow as many tutorials as I can find and as much apple documentation as well.  I just can't see any obvious steps I may have overlooked.

Unless it's the expected behaviour, or an Apple issue I guess.

Thanks for any help - it's driving me nuts!

Answer (score 0):

iOs kill your app when you change iCloudDrive state. This is standard iOs behavior you can check this with build in applications(Safari for example).